# Paralell computing - divisors of large numbers

Tags: parallelization

Program should return a list of all the divisors of `n!-1` for `n=50,51,...,59` using parallel computing.

Here is my current solution:

```
 Parallelize[
   DeleteDuplicates[
     Flatten[Table[Divisors[n! - 1], {n, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59}]]]]
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know how to handle:

> "Parallelize::nopar1: DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[Divisors[n!-1],{n,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59}]]] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation."

Comment: Seemingly altering to this form can solve the problem: DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@ParallelTable[Divisors[n! - 1], {n, Range[50,100]}]

Comment: I suspect that this is because `DeleteDuplicates` needs to see the whole list to do its job: its operation cannot conceptually be parallelized. Table, on the other hand, can be handily parallellized. In other words, the `Parallelize` algorithms are not smart enough to identify this issue, so they give up. Generally speaking, however, parallelizing code is a difficulty task even for humans, and I can't fault the algorithm. As a hint, those commands for which a `Parallel*` version exists (e.g. `ParallelTable`) are the easiest to parallelize, so you should try to use those  preferentially.

Comment: Replace `{n, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59}` with `{n, {50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59}}`